# How to unlink images from folder and subfolder and also from database?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to unlink my images from folder,sub folder and database.It is   successfully being deleted from database.But I can't unlink images from my folder and sub folder.The 2 folders are:

```
$path="uploads/";
$path2="uploads/thumbnail";
```

here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $path="uploads/";
    $path2="uploads/thumbnail";
    $delete=mysql_query("select * from photos where id='$id'");
    $del=mysql_fetch_array($delete);
    $image=$del['image_name'];
    $image1=$del['thumb'];//this variable stores the image from database
    $img=$image.$image1;
    $dir=$path.$path2;
    $unlink=$img.$dir;
    unlink($unlink);
    $sql2=mysql_query("delete from photos where id='$id'");
    if(!$sql2)
    {
        echo "not deleted";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Deleted";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
  $img=$image.$image1;
  $dir=$path.$path2;
  $unlink=$img.$dir;
  unlink($unlink);
```

With

```
$img = $path.$image ;
$img2 = $path2.$image1 ;

unlink($img);
unlink($img2);
```

Comment: Sir I can't unlink sub folder images other one successfully deleted

Comment: replace $path2="uploads/thumbnail"; with $path2="uploads/thumbnail/";

Comment: Warning: unlink(uploads/): Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\rashi\album\album.php on line 82

Warning: unlink(uploads/thumbnail/): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\rashi\album\album.php on line 83
Deleted                                                                                                             This error occurs while i am deleting